# Unavailable Items in Power Options

Tags: windows-10

Some items of Power Options are missing in my Windows 10:

[image]

This window, which is in French, has two options under Veille (Sleep): **Veille après (Sleep after**) and **Mettre en veille prolongée après (Hibernate after)**. Two additional options should be available: **Allow hibrid sleep** and **Allow wake timers**. Why aren't they there and what can be done to change this?

Answer (score 1):

Run the command:

```
powercfg -a
```

and check whether it says this:

```
Hybrid Sleep
    The hypervisor does not support this standby state.
```

If that's the case, Hyper-V is blocking Hybrid Sleep, and
the only way to restore it is to uninstall Hyper-V.